# No matches found for correct globbing

Tags: zsh, glob

I want to list all .c files, except .mod.c files. I use zsh 5.2 (x86_64-debian-linux-gnu) with oh-my-zsh. The pattern I use is following:

```
$ ls *.c      
ipmi_bt_sm.c    ipmi_devintf.mod.c     ipmi_msghandler.c  
ipmi_powernv.c  ipmi_poweroff.mod.c    ipmi_si.mod.c
ipmi_ssif.c     ipmi_watchdog.mod.c    ipmi_devintf.c
ipmi_kcs_sm.c   ipmi_msghandler.mod.c  ipmi_poweroff.c
ipmi_si_intf.c  ipmi_smic_sm.c         ipmi_watchdog.c
$ ls *.c~mod.c
zsh: no matches found: *.c~mod.c
$ ls .*.c~aoesuthaoestuhsththsh
zsh: no matches found: .*.c~aoesuthaoestuhsththsh
```

I'm sure that '*.c~mod.c' is correct, because this is exactly what is proposed at following web-site.

http://www.strcat.de/zsh/ :

> ls *.c~lex.c matches all .c files except lex.c

Do I have to enable something specific for extended globbing? Or disable something which hinders this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you need to make sure extended globbing is turned on:
`setopt extended_glob`

(You'll probably want that in `.zshrc`)

As for your pattern, what you want is `*.c~*.mod.c`.

The way it works is `pattern1~pattern2`, and it yields all the matches of `pattern1`, minus all the matches of `pattern2`. What you had was "Everything that ends in .c, minus mod.c". What you want is really "eveything that ends in .c, minus everything that ends in .mod.c", which is what I give above.